# package was built with an out-of-date version of the Windows SDK Validation error while submitting windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

I had developed windows 8 app and Retargeted in windows 8.1 app using visual studio 2013 express preview and my OS is windows 8.1 preview .
But while uploading my package its getting errors like this.

This package was built with an out-of-date version of the Windows SDK. Please use latest version.

I had updated the Windows sdk also that was released on Oct 17th of this month .

Answer (score 0):

Have you replaced the references to the original SDK DLL files with references to the new SDK?